# Auto Generate Entity Proxy in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, jpa

Is there a way to auto-generate the EntityProxy from an Entity in eclipse ?

For example: 
 right click -> generate Proxy ??

this is so I don't have to code by hand all the methods I'm using

I'm using GWT + JPA

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an Eclipse plugin just for this purpose if you want to try :
https://github.com/nmorel/GenerateGwtRfProxy

It's pretty basic (no support for inheritance) but it covers what you are asking.